# In my cocos2dx project "Google play game services", was applied

Tags: cocos2d-x, google-play-services

*sorry for my poor English*

In my cocos2dx project "Google play game services", was applied. An error has occurred. This is the part immediately below.

```
"Initializing Your Games Client in Android"

…MyAppName.java…

A to B should be replaced.

 ( A ) public class MyAppName extends Cocos2dxActivity
 ( B ) public class MyAppName extends BaseGameActivity
```

Replaced by B, an error occurs. Part of the error is as follows:

source code : `mCocos2dxGLSurfaceView = onCreateView();`

error message:

```
The method onCreateView(String, Context, AttributeSet) in the type FragmentActivity is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

How do I fix the error?
help me ~~

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a base Activity (Cocos2dxActivity), you should just use the GameHelper class provided in BaseGameUtils.

BaseGameActivity is just a wrapper that uses GameHelper.

Comment: Thank you very much. Specifically, how do I apply?

Comment: I tried as follows. but An error has occurred. error message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;

public class myAppName extends Cocos2dxActivity implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener {

 …..
 …..
 public static GameHelper helper;

 ……. 
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  helper = new GameHelper(this);

Comment: Do the samples properly work in your workspace?
If not, follow this guide: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

I've used BaseGameActivity and made it inherit from Cocos2dxActivity instead of FragmentActivity.
Than I replaced my Activity to inherit from BaseGameActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I have a open source implementation for Cocos2d-x and Google Play Game Services for ios and Android maybe you can check because I'm already using BaseGameActivity.

https://github.com/cpinan/Cocos2dX_GooglePlayGamesServices

Check the proj.android and check the source code.

Maybe it can help you.